# What is Proxmox doing when the disk copy is at 100%?

Tags: nfs, proxmox

When moving some of my pve disks from a NFS share to lvm-thin, the server always sits at 100% for about 20 minutes. This happens every time. Maybe it's verifying the new disk or removing the old disk, but it would be nice if it told me. Does anyone know? I'm not sure it always logs 100% line twice, but after reaching 100 it should only take a moment to finish.
[image: What is is doing?]

Comment: how long does it take to get to 100%?

Comment: It's a file copy so it depends on the size. The total duration (including the "hang") for the job that screenshot was 4 hours. I didn't actually time how long it was at 100%, but (at least for small copies) it's the longest part.
Maybe I'll make a small disk and copy it with a stopwatch handy.

Comment: so, the copy takes 4 hours, and then it `sits at 100% for about 20 minutes`?

Comment: Yes. Each percent only took 2-3 minutes, so why is 100 taking so long? If this is normal for Proxmox then what's it doing?